# userControl "The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Some of my webpages suffer this because I use an object belongs to ascx.cs in ascx

this is my ascx.cs:

```
public AnnouncementDetailItem announcement = new AnnouncementDetailItem();
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string qry ="...";
                SPListItem spListItems = BaseSPList.GetItems(ListName, qry)[0];

                if (spListItems != null)
                {
                    announcement = new AnnouncementDetailItem() {
                        Title = spListItems.Fields["Title"].ToString(),
                        SubTitle = spListItems["SubTitle"].ToString(),
                        Content = spListItems["Content"].ToString(),
                        BroadcastDate = spListItems["BroadcastDate"].ToCustomDateTime(),
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CoreException.WriteToLog("Announcements WP", ex);
            }
        }
```

ascx page(even if I remove these content still same error occurs): I also share namespaces sorry for messing if its cause to.

```
   <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AnnouncementDetail.ascx.cs" Inherits="MaliyeWebPortal.WebParts.AnnouncementDetail.AnnouncementDetail" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MaliyeCore.DTO" %>


   <% if(announcement != null){ %>
<div id="announcementsTabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"> <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#duyuru<%=announcement.ID%>"><%=announcement.Title %></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



  <%   } %>
```

how can I fix it

Comment: Did you register user control in aspx page?

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ YEs I also edited post with assmblies about it. is there any more necessary ?

Comment: refer this http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/

Comment: I am using like this  <%@ Register src="../path_of_usercontrol/Pager.ascx" tagname="Pager" tagprefix="uc1" %>

Comment: and then  <uc1:Pager id="uc_Pager" runat="server" PageSize="15"    /> in html code